# Android Project Compilation error, on excluding files at compile time

Tags: android, maven

I have to build Android Project using **MAVEN**.In that I am using maven-compiler-plugin **3.1** and want to exclude some files and packages at compile time (Compiler should not read those files and packages which are excluded).

In Excluded files, I have use ISO-8859-1 symbols,on that lines compiler throw error that **"unmappable character for encoding UTF-8"**. 
Please help me, Here is my code:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.1</version>
   <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
      <excludes>
         <exclude>**/myapp/activity/*</exclude>
         <exclude>**/myapp/*</exclude>
         <exclude>**/myapp/services/*</exclude>
      </excludes>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Change the encoding of the appropriate files...or configure the whole project accordingly...Excluding is never a good idea, cause this looks like you need to separate those things..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I have done changes in pom.xml and my problem get solved. I had done changes in excluding files. Here is my correct code :-

```
    <plugin>   
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.6</source>
      <target>1.6</target>
      <excludes>
         <exclude>**/myapp/activity/**</exclude>
         <exclude>**/myapp/**</exclude>
         <exclude>**/myapp/services/**</exclude>
      </excludes>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```